# how to export a react-redux project as a node_module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to export a redux project as a `node_module` that has an index.js shown below (simplified):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import App from './App.jsx';

const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(), promiseMiddleware()];
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);
const preloadedState = {};

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    middlewareEnhancer
);

 const ExampleModule = (props) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default ExampleModule;
```

In my main application:

```
...
import ExampleModule from 'example-module';

class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <ExampleModule />;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ state }) {
    return {
        state: state
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { 
        actions: bindActionCreators(require('..').actions, dispatch) 
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Application);
```

This throws an error:
`bundle.js:349 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"`

I'm assuming it's because this essentially creates nested `<Providers>` which is against Redux's methodology of one store.

My question would be what would be the best way to go about publishing a node_module that has a redux store in it?

Comment: Normally you'd export reducers and components separately, like, https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/ Why do you need a new store?

Comment: @DvidSilva found the answer here! https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps

It keeps the store local to the component.